# How to know the CPU usage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cpu-usage

I was in a online classroom in google meet, and i discovered that google meet can obtain the CPU usage data in real time, and i got curious, because javascript normally doesnt allow to do things like this.

how is it possible? i cant find anything that says about collecting CPU usage data in javascript.

Comment: Probably sent from backend.

Comment: Did you perhaps install a chrome extension?

Comment: no, i didnt install a chrome extension

Answer (score -1):

The most near thing I found is knowing the number of CPU cores that the client is using.

```
console.log(navigator.hardwareConcurrency)
```

It'll return an integer. However, if I'm not mistaken you can calculate this with Node.js.